# Laravel - Deals properly with application's logic errors

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling, exception

I try to figure out what is the best way to handle application's logic errors. Let's say that my app is managing a stock of computer.

The user can do lots of action : add, edit, delete etc... But each assets has a status : In use, In stock, Damaged etc...

Some status restricts the user to do some action. For example if the pc is In use , you can't delete it.

This is just an example, and my app is more complex, with a lots of different ressources, which all deals with different status. So I don't want to manage that by using conditions in controllers. It's gonna be really messy at the end...

I'm using a service layer to deal with business logic. Firstly I thought about using Exception into the service layer, but after reading few articles it seams that is bad thing to use Exception for logic errors.

What do you think about that ?

Comment: Yea I'd write the logic in model classes. Exceptions are usually used for incorrect input, etc for functions or system errors like database connection fail.

Comment: [Good example](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/state) of handling state transitions by phpunit creator. Throwing an exception representing invalid operation was about to happen is ok.